# How to create an on-chain proof that user 0x12423 is Discord user 'elonmusk'

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm building a protocol where user can issue NFTs according to their web2 achievements.

Users, on the front-end, connect with metamask + other auth2 mechanism (such as Twitter, Github, Discord ....).

For example, user 0x12423 connects with Metamask and authenticate with Discord (username 'elonmusk') so now my platform knows, on the client side, that user 0x12423 corresponds to 'elonmusk' on Discord.

Let's say that I want to issue to user 0x12423 a specific NFT badge according to his achievements on Discord (user name 'elonmusk').

How can I bring the issue an on-chain proof that user 0x12423 is Discord user 'elonmusk' in order to allow only 0x12423 mint specif badges based on 'elonmusk' achievements ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it off-chain by having this address sign a mint transaction and then letting your backend call the mint function to issue the signer the token that they earned.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please? What would be the message signed by the address? And would the mint function have call permission restricted to my backend wallet in this case?